# If $A/B \cong C/B$, then is it true that $A\cong C$?

Tags: modules

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be $R$- submodules of an $R$- module $M$ and $A/B \cong C/B$. Then is it true that $A\cong C$? Here $B$ is a submodule of both $A$ and $C$.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the copy of $\mathbb Z/2$ that sits inside $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2$ and inside $\mathbb Z/4$.